# Controlled Voltage Environments

Tags: ratings

I was reading the spec for a patch cable (Ponoma B-36-02) and when came across the following:

*"Operating Voltage: 
     Hand-held Testing: 30VAC/60 VDC Max.
     Hands free testing in Controlled Voltage Environment: 5000 WVDC"*

I was puzzled by the extreme difference between the two operating voltage ratings. What is a controlled voltage environment? Also, is there a specific regulatory body that has defined "Hand-held" and "Hands free" and "Controlled Voltage Environment"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Controlled Voltage Environment* is basically one where you aren't.

The testing voltage for the cable is ideally 5,000V.  You don't want to be testing it with that sort of voltage by hand.  For safety reasons you shouldn't hand-test with anything over 30V AC (or 60V DC).

Above 30V AC it is possible to get an electric shock, which is to be avoided if at all possible, for obvious reasons.

Therefore testing with voltages above that, up to the upper test limit of 5,000V (I assume this is the voltage at which the insulation would start to break down), must be done in an isolated "Hands Off" environment.

Such an environment has strict controls on the flow of the high voltages - both physical (breakers, safety switches, current limiters, dual controls, etc) and procedural (Yes, RTFM :} ), and only trained operators will be able to access and use such facilities.

Answer (score 2):

- Summary:

  As well as the technical issues there are regulatory ones involved.

  They are protecting themselves legally by saying that people may only use it for "hands on" purposes when it is used in conditions which are deemed "person safe" for regulatory purposes. The voltage range includes the standard telephone supply voltage of 50 volts.

  The voltage range specified is termed ELV (Extra Low voltage) and has significant regulatory provisions & protections.

ELV (Extra Low Voltage) is a voltage level which is defined as "safe" for many purposes. The exact definition of what constitutes ELV varies among regulatory bodies, and there has been some very serious confusion in the international standards area in recent times when quite incompatible DC and AC values were published *) but within a given administration, having equipment which involves only  ELV gives a manufacturer very significant regulatory protections and freedoms.

ELV voltages at one time were "almost safe" but internationally accepted values have become questionably safe in more recent times and the relative danger of acceptable AC and DC values now seem to differ.eg in dry conditions the allowed 50 VAC of IEC61201 (see below) would give you a noticeable shock but a good chance of survival. But I would be very very wary or receiving a good shock from the 120 VDC allowed by the same specification.

ELV definitions almost always include DC voltages of 50V to allow inclusion of standard telecommunications circuits and equipment and may sometimes go to 60 VD or on occasion even 100 VDC. DC content is often specified as "ripple free" to ensure that the peak voltages are not increased by AC content. AC voltages often have about the same peak voltages as the specified DC voltage but sometimes there are significant (and sometimes senseless) differences.

Here is [Wikipedias's comment on ELV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage) with reference to IEC (International Electrotechnical Commission) - a major international standards certification body. They note that -

- The International Electrotechnical Commission and its member organizations define an ELV circuit as one in which the electrical potential of any conductor against earth (ground) is not more than either 25 volts RMS (35 volts peak) for alternating current, or ripple-free 60 volts for direct current under dry conditions. Lower numbers apply in wet conditions, or when large contact areas are exposed to contact with the human body.

Note the **25 VAC / 35 V** peak which match well for sine waves, but the **60 VDC**, which here is *about* twice the peak to peak AC value.

The confusion in standards is shown by this document - [IEC/TS 62257 - Recommendations for small renewable energy and hybrid systems for rural 
electrification – Part 7-1: Generators – Photovoltaic generators](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec62257-7-1%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf) which defines ELV as **50 VAC** or **120 VDC** (with reference to IEC 61201 as source).

---

Excellent document on electronic equipment safety - 150 pages - well worth looking at [ECMA287 Safety of Electronic equipment](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-287.pdf)

[IEC61201 index only](http://ebookbrowse.com/info-iec61201-ed2-0-b-pdf-d95387541)

[IEC61201 Chinese site - RAR of pdf 800 kB - content unknown](http://bz.6jc.cn/gr/2011-02-18/107922.html)

Worth looking at - [Excellent discussion of electric shock safety with reference to IEC 60990](http://www.ifmqs.com.au/images/CTL%20presentation%20Peak%20TC+attachments.pdf)

[Review of hazards for low voltage elecrocution](http://bme.ccny.cuny.edu/faculty/mbikson/biksonmsafevoltagereview.pdf) - note LV not ELV